# Onde está meu erro neste código de Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou com problema em métodos com passagem de parametro, o código roda, porém ele buga quando eu passo a var dentro de um método e recebe como parametro em outro. Sou novo em Ruby.

```
def player_welcome
    puts "Seja bem vindo ao Jogo de Adivinhação !!"
    puts "Criado por Thiago De Bonis Carvalho Saad Saud"
end

def generate_number_raffled
    number_raffled = 100
    number_raffled.to_i
end

def player_choice_name
    puts "Qual seu nome jogador?"
    player_name = gets
    player_name.to_s
end

def player_choice_attempts(player_name)
    puts "Quantas tentativas gostaria de ter " + player_name + "?" 
    number_attempts = gets
    number_attempts.to_i
end

def play_the_game(player_name,number_attempts)
    puts " " + player_name + "você tem " + number_attempts + "."
    for player_attempts in 1..number_attempts
        puts "Adivinhe um número entre 0 e 200..."
        player_kick = gets
        if check_number_raffled(player_kick,number_raffled)
            break
        end
    end
    player_kick.to_i
end

def check_number_raffled(player_kick,number_raffled)
    if player_kick == number_raffled
        puts "Você Acertou !!"
        return true
    end
    if player_kick > number_raffled
        puts "Você errou!!"
        puts "Você digitou um número maior que o do Sorteado, tente novamente.."
    else
        puts "Você errou!!"
        puts "Você digitou um número menor que o do Sorteado, tente novamente.."
        end
end

player_welcome
player_choice_name
player_choice_attempts(player_name)
play_the_game(player_name,number_attempts)
```

Answer (score 1):

player_name é uma variável local. Ela existe apenas no escopo do método (player_choice_name)

Se você fizer @player_name ela agora é uma variável de instancia e é acessível por todos os métodos dentro da classe.

Você pode ler mais aqui: http://strugglingwithruby.blogspot.dk/2010/03/variables.html

Comment: Eu ainda não aprendi essa parte de utilizar @, somente o #{nomeVar} dentro de alguma String, teria um outro jeito mais prático para quem está iniciante, passar por parametro essas variaveis de funções para outras funções? Adicionei a seguinte linha de código, porém ele fica repetindo o código agora, como se tivesse dentro de um While ou chamando a função toda hora. '-'

Comment: Imagem: https://scontent.fsdu5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/14713772_206737486415009_961632780851287076_n.jpg?oh=e484d87d21d415e4ddae82a9b1505bd2&oe=58A030DB

Answer (score 1):

Como o Gleyson já falou, `player_name` é uma variável local do método `player_choice_name`.

A solução dele é válida, porém uma solução melhor do que criar variáveis de instância é pegar o retorno do método, método esse que vc já preparou pra retornar o nome do jogador com a linha `player_name.to_s`, e atribuir esse retorno a outra variável, que será passada como parâmetro para os métodos seguintes:

```
def player_choice_name
  (...)
  player_name.to_s # Esse valor será retornado
end

(...)

player_welcome
player_name = player_choice_name
number_attempts = player_choice_attempts(player_name)
play_the_game(player_name, number_attempts)
```

Repare que a variável `number_attemps` também é local e ocorreria o mesmo erro caso o código chegasse na chamada do método `player_choice_attemps`.